# Android 12 doesn't return location with approximate location permission

Tags: location, fusedlocationproviderclient, android-12, android-api-31

On Pixel 4a with Android 12 (SPB5.210812.002), when approximate location permission is given by the user, no location is returned from `FusedLocationProviderClient`. When I change permission to exact location permission, then I'm able to get location.

I have both coarse and fine location permissions in Manifest, as well as requesting both at runtime.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Once either permission is given, I'm requesting `lastKnownLocation`, as well as requesting for location updates.
With precise location permission, Im getting location shortly, but not when user gives approximate location permission.

For location request priority, I've tried both `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` and `LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY`.

On Android 9 everything works as expected, so I guess this is related to [precise/approximate location permission](https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions#approximate-request), introduced in Android 12.

Here is part of my code:

```
private val fusedLocationClient by lazy { 
        LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext()) 
    }
    private val cts: CancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource()

    private val locationRequest = LocationRequest()
        .setPriority(LOCATION_REQUEST_PRIORITY)
        .setFastestInterval(MIN_TIME_BETWEEN_STAMPS_IN_MILLIS) // 1000
        .setInterval(TIME_BETWEEN_STAMPS_IN_MILLIS) // 10000

    private val locationCallback = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(locationResult: LocationResult?) {
            locationResult?.locations?.firstOrNull()?.let {
                userLocation = it
                onUserLocationUpdated()
            }
        }
    }


    private fun onLocationPermissionGranted() {
        if (!requireContext().isLocationEnabled()) {
            requireContext().showLocationPermissionRequiredDialog {
                onBackPressed()
            }
        } else {
            try {
                getCurrentLocation()
                fusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, locationCallback, Looper.getMainLooper())
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                onBackPressed()
            }
        }
    }

 
    private fun getCurrentLocation() {
        fusedLocationClient.getCurrentLocation(
            LOCATION_REQUEST_PRIORITY,
            cts.token
        ).addOnSuccessListener { location: Location? ->
            if (location != null) {
                userLocation = location
                onUserLocationUpdated()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am seeing the same thing on a pixel 4 (same OS version). A small addition, the location is returned on Android 11 and 10 just fine with the same code.

Comment: Another small follow up here, I received the latest android build (SP1A.210812.015) and at first things worked.  But it seems after a while the same issue pops up, and to get around it you have to restart your device. I haven't timed how long after a restart things work.

Comment: I think once or twice out of many tests, location was returned with approximate location permission, but it:
- took longer time (around 30-60 sec);
- was only one-time reply, no periodic replies, even though I've subscribed.

Comment: I've got the same thing. After requesting location updates, the status bar isn't even showing a location icon and no locations are received at all.

Comment: @Myroslav Would you please inform me how you solved this problem?

Comment: @Mansi Havent really solved it, to be honest. I know there is newer build available S2B3.220205.007.A1, so maybe they've changed something in this built, but I haven't checked it myself yet.

Comment: @Myroslav I solved this problem by using the "LiveData" class.

Answer (score 0):

On Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, users can request that your app retrieve only approximate location information, even when your app requests the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION runtime permission.

To handle this potential user behavior, don't request the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission by itself. Instead, request both the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission and the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permission in a single runtime request.

If you try to request only ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, the system ignores the request on some releases of Android 12. If your app targets Android 12 or higher, the system logs the following error message in Logcat:

ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION must be requested with ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

Here you can find it in the official Android Documentation:

https://developer.android.com/training/location/permissions

Comment: Yes, I'm requesting both in one request: 
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.